# Weekly report with sharepoint lists

Tags: sharepoint-online

I received to create a reporting tool either with Excel or on Sharepoint. Every week a fix number of departments have to report on a couple of fixed topics with fix answers Yes/No or a number 10%, 20%... Each month this data will be assessed for progress and built some charts, bar or wathever. For one week this is a 2 dimension sheet. I call this Table weekly_report_#week:

Departement ABCDED

Question 1

Question 2

...

How would you do this? Cool would be the follwoing idea but I don't know how to do this. Every week an empty list is provided. Short before preparing the new empty list for the next week, people can update the current list. On due date the following happens: The current weeks list gets a date stamp and is attached to the  list of the week before. This gives me a chain of blocks

weekly_report_#week1

weekly_report_#week2

weekly_report_#week3

Every month then like in a pivot chart, four weeks are analyzed and shown in charts to show progres.

Is this possible automatically of course :-)

Best regards,

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use SharePoint OOTB list - Surveys, there you can create questions with defined answers, etc. There are also some graphical summary of responses or you can create Data Connection to Excel from this list and create PowerPivot and Better Graphs here. 
You can create from this survey list a template and for each month create new or create column in this list for defining year and month for filtering.

[Create survey](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-survey-ea52a787-822e-4f7e-b5ed-77bb14df3aba)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your great idea. While digging on this I have found another solution - Microsoft Forms. I create a survey from Excel online and send around this link. Also quite comfortable. Every month I'm sending this form. It is time stamped and in Excel easy to filter and analyze.

Best regards,
Daniel